# Conversion Between Android Time vs Java Time

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am having a little bit of trouble with a time conversion between an android phone (Nexus one) and a java server. Everything I have read says that they are the same but when I am converting a long time stamp from i seem to lose 1 hour (exactly).

Specifically, If I run the following code on the android device I get the following output

Code:

```
Calendar g = Calendar.getInstance();
g.setTimeInMillis(1340661899000L);
Log.d(TAG, g.getTime().toLocaleString());
```

Output: 
Jun 25, 2012 6:04:59 PM

Which I think is correct, but when I run the exact same code on a java server I get a the same day but 1 hour earlier

Code:

```
Calendar g = Calendar.getInstance();
g.setTimeInMillis(1340661899000L);
System.out.println(g.getTime().toLocaleString());
```

Output: 
25-Jun-2012 5:04:59 PM

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Both the server ad the phone are located in the same place (not that it should matter) and the clocks on both the server box and the phone match

Comment: You probably don't want to use localized time in communication between client and server, since you can't be sure what the time locale on the client will be.

Comment: the value 1340661899000L shouldnt be a local time, I just want to display what a given time would be in the device timezone

Comment: Expecting both client and server to be in the same timezone/mode is what I was suggesting you avoid.

Answer (score 4):

Considering it's a difference of one hour, could you possible have DST (Daylight Savings Time) set on server and not on the phone or vice-versa?

Comment: well now I just feel like a moron. Ya for some reason the phone version of toLocaleString wasnt taking DST into account even though the clock on the phone was the correct time.

Comment: @JohnS This is an example of why you should avoid working in local date-time values. Keep your data communications, business logic, data storage, and server clock all in [UTC](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (with few exceptions). Convert to local time-zone-adjusted only when expected by the user or consumer of your data.

Answer (score 1):

What Chris is trying to say is that your phone and server may be configured to different timezones.

Try printing the result of `cal.getTimeZone()`. should this be the issue you will want to pick a timezone to use for communications. For instance:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));
```

According to the JavaDocs the calendar instances use the default timezones reported by:

```
TimeZone.getDefault()
```

Despite your server and mobile being set to the same TimeZone may not necessarily mean they use the same default TimeZone.